# HTML Object Tag Issue

Tags: html

I am using a object tag inside a `div` to load a html page.

The loaded html page's height is more than the div's height.

The `div` is not expanding itself to accommodate the inner dynamic content.

How to solve this issue?

```
<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo"  style="overflow:auto;">
 <div data-role="header" style="background-color:brown;font-color:orange;" >
    <a href="#pageone" data-icon="back" id="back">Back</a>
    <a href="" data-icon="exit" id="exit" onclick="xit()">exit</a>
 <h1 style="font-color:white">events</h1>
  </div>
    <object style="width:100%;background-color:orange;height:100%;" scrolling="no"      type="text/html" data="http://localhost:8080/events.html">
</object>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the style of the div:

```
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto;
```